# How do I use getch() with arrow keys?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm teaching myself ncurses by making a small game, and I have some questions about how to detect arrow keys. I have keypad set to true so getch() returns a single value when I press one of them, but it returns the value in decimal while the defined keycodes are in octal.

For example, when I press up, getch() returns 259, but KEY_UP is defined as 0403, which is just 259 in octal. I can convert it to octal, but then I can't use it with normal keys anymore.

Example case:

```c
int key = convert_dec_to_oct(getch());
switch(key){
  case KEY_UP :
    // do stuff
    break;
  case 'q' :
    // no longer triggers on q since we converted the keycode to octal
    break;
}
```

Edited for clarification.

Comment: `getch` returns an `int`, doesn't it? So there is no base. A number is a number is a number. You're already getting the value you want. Can you clarify the problem/error you're getting?

Comment: Have you done any research? Specifically, about the constants that the curses library gives you (like `KEY_RIGHT`, `KEY_LEFT`, etc...). I'd suggest starting with a good tutorial like [this one](http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html#input). Don't forget to call `keypad(stdstr, TRUE)`!

Comment: @scohe001 Not sure why you think they haven't, when they literally talked about `KEY_UP` in the question...

Comment: I recall in some cases you have to read twice to get all of an arrow key. I don't recall if it applies to `getch` or just when you're mucking around with windows messages.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Like I said, when I call getch() and press up on the keyboard, it returns 259. KEY_UP is defined in curses.h as 0403, so I can't do something like if(getch() == KEY_UP), I have to convert 259 into octal or 403 into decimal first. Just wondering if there was a better way to do that.

Comment: @ThatEvilChickenNextDoor You don't though. 0403 octal is equal to 259 decimal. No conversion is needed -- you just need to compare them. They are the same value, and `==` compares values.

Comment: You can compare decimal and octal directly in C++, they're two representations of the same number. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/z18Waa

Comment: Let your compiler do the conversion for you if you want to use [octal constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal): "octal-literal is the digit zero (0) followed by zero or more octal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)", as in `0403 != 403`.

Comment: _"when I call getch() and press up on the keyboard, it returns 259. KEY_UP is defined in curses.h as 0403, so I can't do something like if(getch() == KEY_UP), I have to convert 259 into octal or 403 into decimal first"_ That is simply not true. Those are the same integer. The base you (or the curses authors) choose when you write an integer as a literal in your source code does not affect anything. (Speaking practically, consider that the integer is stored in binary regardless.) Tell us what _actual_ problem you're having so we can help you, not the problem you've assumed/guessed it is ;)

Comment: Yep, turns out I was being dumb with another part of my code and the comparison works fine. Thanks for the help! Probably would have been stuck thinking this was the problem for another long while without you guys